# Install pykml Python module in Windows 7 (64bits)

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, pykml

I am new into Python, so maybe my questions is stupid, but I am not able to install [pykml module](http://packages.python.org/pykml/).

Visiting its website, there are no Windows instructions for installing. Anyway I tried installing easy_install, and that doesn't work either.

Since now, I have done:

- Install Python 2.7.3
- Manually add `C:\Python27` to `PATH` enviroment variable
- Also added `C:\Python27\Scripts` to allow easy_install execution
- Executed `easy_install lykml`. It is not found at easy_install repositories (`'Could not find suitable distribution for Requeriment.parse('pykml')'`)
- Tried `easy_install pip` to try installing with pip. Same error than before.

My Windows 7 is 64 bits. How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I have found some packages built in .exe for windows 64 bits and installed them successfully. For example easy_install was installed in that way. But other times I try installing an .exe package distribution, as pyserial, and installation wizard says `'No Python installation found in the registry'`. Could that be related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to install these [unofficial binaries for lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)? Use the `amd64` version that corresponds to your Python version. With `lxml` installed your `pyxml` installation should succeed too.

Comment: It is not pyxml but pykml what I am installing. I fact, it relies on lxml, and I did just as you just said and that worked, but not the pykml after that.

Comment: Did you try to install pykml by downloading it from [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykml/0.1.0), extracting the distribution from the gzipped tar and running `python setup.py install`?

Comment: The direct install worked well for me, as suggested by @NMusatti. The current version is on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pykml/). For some strange reasons, PyPI only _sometimes_ finds PyKML when you search for it. Maybe that is also the reason why `pip` fails?